# Colliding particles at speeds aproaching c

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum

(In natural units where $\hbar=c=1$.) Two particles are to be collided. Each of these particles has a rest mass of 0.9 GeV and they will be collided at equal but opposite speeds. What is the minimum speed required for the collision to produce a single particle of rest mass 5.6 GeV?

I've written down the relativistic equations for momentum and energy, but haven't had much luck. I got to $$\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma_2} = \frac{28v}{9u}$$ and attempted to calculate the ratio $v/u$, but that didn't really go anywhere helpful. Any hints would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what are v and u? btw you should add the homework tag

Comment: Since the particles are identical, including speed, you should only need to consider one. Is it not enough to find what velocity gives E = 2.8 GeV, using the relativistic relation between E, p and m?

Comment: @ anna v: u and v are the velocities of the particle(s) before and after the collision respectively.

Comment: You just need the total energy measured in the lab frame to equal 5.6GeV. With this energy the two particles could fuse to create a stationary particle of mass 5.6GeV.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the velocity using this approach:

$$\gamma = \frac{E_\text{kin}+E_\text{rest}}{E_\text{rest}}; \quad\beta=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}}; \quad v=\beta c.$$

where the total energy for each of the two particles is half of the mass of the particle that you want to obtain.

This is the sloppy-theoretical-minimum energy: it requires the two particles to fuse completely into a new (stationary) particle. There are only few processes  like this that do not violate some conservation laws (only the fully bosonic processes)! Normally we need to create a couple of particle-antiparticle. Moreover for a complete fusion also the two initial objects must be each other's antiparticles: the given rest mass may suggest that you are dealing with a proton-antiproton collision. However, these are composite particles and it is very unlikely that they annihilate completely in a collision.